# SQL to get two column records in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have two tables, both contain field `telephone_number`. I want to find all the distinct/unique telephone numbers from both the table. Can this be done?

For eg

```
Table A 
telephone_number
123 
123
345 

Table B
telephone_number
1234 
123 
678

Output Table 
123 
345 
678 
1234
```

thanks

Sorry for formatting

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an unambiguous explanation would hep.  Do you want a list of unique telephone numbers in both tables?  Do you want telephone numbers that are only in one table?  Do you want telephone numbers that appear only once?

Comment: Sorry about that, i was adding example but was struggling with formatting.

Comment: Why do you store phone numbers in two different tables?

Comment: They are coming from different data sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the distinct telephone numbers in both tables, use `union`:

```
select telephone_number
from t1
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select telephone_number
from t2;
```